# How to export table visual with conditional formatting from Power BI to Excel?

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, daxstudio

I have a table that I want to export to excel with conditional formatting inclusive from Power Bi table visual. How should I go about doing so? I would like to retain it in an as-is manner if possible.

[image]

Is there a way to maintain the formatting and appearance in excel??

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Comment: not even with DAX Studio??

Comment: I don't see how DAX Studio would help.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry but in Power BI you can only export raw data. No conditional formatting, no totals.

If you really need this, investigate Report Builder.

Otherwise, you might want to investigate the Analyze in Excel tool.

Comment: analyze in excel did not work, I'll look into report builder